# Can someone explain "cascaded" evaluation of inequalities of log probabilities?

Tags: probability, inequality, logarithms, markov-chains, uniform-distribution

I am working with Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) methods and I have come across several examples of "cascaded evaluation" of log probabilities.

For example, suppose you have a rejection criterion of the form:

$$r > p_1p_2p_3$$

where $r$ is a random number drawn from the uniform distribution $U(0,1)$, and $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ are independent probabilities with values between 0 and 1.

In log probability, the inequality can be written as:

$$\mathrm{log}(r) > \mathrm{log}(p_1)+\mathrm{log}(p_2)+\mathrm{log}(p_3)\tag{1}$$

In order to save compute time, I have seen that some people evaluate the inequality by doing a "cascaded evaluation":

- Draw $r_1$ as a single random number from the uniform distribution
- If $\mathrm{log}(r_1) > \mathrm{log}(p_1)$, then reject

  - Else Draw $r_2$ as a single random number from the uniform distribution
  - If $\mathrm{log}(r_2) > \mathrm{log}(p_2)$, then reject

    -Else Draw $r_3$ as a single random number from the uniform distribution

    -If $\mathrm{log}(r_3) > \mathrm{log}(p_3)$, then reject

This saves time because if you reject on the first if statement, you can avoid all the additional inequalities. However, I don't understand how this method satisfies the original inequality in $(1)$. Drawing multiple random numbers and evaluating each part of the summation separately doesn't seem to make sense because the full summation could still hold even if you reject all the individual parts.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or is there something special about the properties of log probabilities and/or uniform distributions and/or inequalities?

Any info is appreciated.

Comment: Do $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$ come from the same distribution as $r$?

Comment: @AmaanM Yes, they are all from the uniform distribution. I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to accept with probability $p_1 p_2 p_3$ then it suffices to do three independent checks that would result in acceptance with probability $p_i$, and accept only if all three checks passed (since then the probability that all three checks passed is $p_1 p_2 p_3$ as desired).

One way to describe this mathematically is to say that if $X_i$ are independent Bernoulli($p_i$) variables then $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a Bernoulli($\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$) variable. Then as soon as any $X_i$ is known to be zero, the product $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ can be short-circuit evaluated without needing to know the other $X_i$.

Comment: I am sort of confused about why it is faster than just doing *one* random uniform draw and accept if it's larger than $p_1p_2p_3$. What does one gain by doing this -- are multiplications considered very expensive (more than taking logarithms)?

Comment: @ClementC. It might save time if you are running some iteration such that some of the $p_i$ depend on the state, and maybe $p_3$ is expensive to evaluate. But in general I agree that this is a weird thing to do, because usually the rand() call is the bottleneck in these kinds of things. I also don't really see why you would take logarithms anyway, you could just check $r_1<p_1,r_2<p_2$ etc.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the quick response. If you take 3 separate $r$ values, then how do those relate to the original inequality?

Comment: I see, I didn't think of the setting where one may have to loop over something or update frequently one of the $p_i$'s (but not another).

Comment: @Darcy They don't. The original $r$ is never generated. You just generate a check that succeeds with probability $p_1 p_2 p_3$ which is what you were trying to do at the beginning anyway.

Comment: @ClementC In my case, it is the evaluation of the probabilities that is the bottleneck. The evaluation of $p_1$ and $p_2$  take about 0.1 seconds each, but the evaluation of $p_3$ takes about 2 seconds. If I am running thousands (or millions) of iterations, it is much faster to avoid $p_3$ if possible.

Comment: @Darcy What you are doing in both cases is simulating a Bernoulli with parameter $p_1p_2p_3$. There is not immediate correspondence between how you do that (either thresholding a single uniform  $R$, or thresholding separately three independent $R_i$'s, but in the end this is what happens: you either simulate $X$ directly with parameter $p_1p_2p_3$, or simulate three independent Bernoulli $X_1,X_2,X_3$. So the argument is about the distribution of $X$ versus $X_1X_2X_3$, not about $R$ versus $R_1,R_2,R_3$

Comment: @Ian Okay, I guess I am just overthinking it. Is there a way to write out the intuition in a mathematically rigorous way?

Comment: @Darcy In math notation you could say that if $X_i$ are Bernoulli($p_i$) distributed and independent then $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is Bernoulli($\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$) distributed. Now you can (sometimes) short-circuit evaluate that product, since it's $1$ if and only if all factors are $1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Ian Great answer. This makes it very clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Darcy By the way, depending on how exactly your evaluation code works, it might also save time to only run it until you can determine the result of the check. For example if $r=0.2,p_1=0.5,p_2=0.5$, as soon as you know for certain which side of $0.8$ $p_3$ is on, you can stop improving your evaluation of it.

Comment: @Darcy If I have answered your question, it would be good if you clicked the check mark so the question leaves the unanswered queue :) You also get a small amount of reputation for doing this.